# Conta de desenvolvedor

Tags: android

Estou tentando abrir uma conta, e tenho as seguintes duvidas:

- Posso pagar a taxa de desenvolvedor com cartão de credito internacional pre-pago (o travel card da master card)?
- Sou desenvolvedora autonoma, (logo trabalho em casa), e a conta pede para fornecer um endereço para ser exibido ao usuario para poder vender apps!!! Como assim??? Sacanagem pô! Não posso e nem quero meu endereço divulgado pra qualquer um! O campo não é de preenchimento obrigatorio, porem fala que se não por o app e/ou a conta pode ser suspensos... Como vcs resolveram isso? Pq não vejo endereço nenhum no google play.
- Como vcs fazem para receber o dinheiro da venda dos apps? A google deposita na conta de vcs? Se sim, tem q ser algum tipo de conta especifica, ou conta corrente mesmo? E onde vcs informam essa conta? pq não vi nenhum campo para por a conta bancaria para deposito...

Por favor, estou precisando urgente abrir essa conta, mas não sei por onde começar, já li a documentação, mas muita coisa não é dita lá, como esses detalhes acima, só quem ja criou a conta para saber mesmo, então se alguem puder me responder eu agradeceria muito.

Comment: Claro que aparece o endereço, veja esse da google, clique em "leia mais" e verá Mountain View(sede da google) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=pt_BR

Comment: A senhorita entende de inglês? tenta perguntar aqui. https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Senhorita,
Quanto ao endereço isso faz parte nos termos para desenvolvedores https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html , quanto ao pagamento quando paguei a taxa exigida utilizei um cartão pré-pago internacional e ocorreu tudo bem, caso não ocorra com tu, melhor é contactar a administradora do cartão.

Comment: Oi Hugo, obrigada. Como vc faz com a questão do endereço? Vc tb é autonomo como eu? O @diegofm comentou q tem sim o endereço, fui ver e nos pagos tem mesmo, porem nem todos são completos(ex:[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sikebo.antimo.material.icons] ou [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.armaker.essappx&hl=pt_BR]), alguns tem só cidade e pais, isso basta? Obrigada.

Comment: Inicialmente utilizei um endereço de um escritório virtual na época que criei a minha conta, não é necessário tu informar o seu endereço completo como número da residência por exemplo.
Melhores cumprimentos para sí.